# eloquent - accessing the property of parent model in shared one to many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have the following eloquent models:

[User]

```
public function studentProfile()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\StudentProfile');
}

public function tutorProfile()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\TutorProfile');
}
```

[StudentProfile]

```
public function user()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function tutorialLogs()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\TutorialLog', 'student_profile_id');
}
```

[TutorProfile]

```
public function user()
 {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }

 public function tutorialLogs()
 {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TutorialLog', 'tutor_profile_id');
 }
```

[TutorialLog]

```
public function tutorProfile()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TutorProfile');
}

public function studentProfile()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\StudentProfile');
}
```

My database structure also is like this:

[users]

```
id
fname
```

[student_profiles]

```
id
notes
user_id
```

[tutor_profiles]

```
id
speciality
user_id
```

[tutorial_logs]

```
id
notes
student_profile_id
tutor_profile_id
```

I am trying to get the tutorial logs for a tutor based on the tutor_profile_id. I have done that, however when I am going to get the tutor name or student name I can’t.

Here is my code:

```
$tutor = User::whereId(Auth::user()->id)->first();

// get the tutorial logs
$tutorial_logs = $tutor->tutorProfile->tutorialLogs()->orderBy('date')->get();
```

I don’t know how to access the student fname or tutor fname in the view.

Any help? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The student `fname` you can access:

```
{{ $tutor->student_profile->user->fname }}
```

The tutor `fname` you can access

```
{{ $tutor->user->fname }}
```

Comment: Or you can use `Mappable` from this package so it happens automatically https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence